# Include a "pdf window" in a .ppt

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I am having a .pdf of 1002 slides pages. These pages are snapshots taken at different time steps. I am willing to include this .pdf in a powerpoint presentation so that I can easily move from one snapshot to another with some keys. Because the rest of my presentation contains animations, I cannot simply make a .pdf out of my .ppt and add the 1002 pages in it. I would rather need to add the 1002 pages in my .ppt in a convenient way.

I am asking for advice for doing so. Two things are to be maximized:

- Easiness (and speed) of transitions
- Control over the flow during the presentation

**Gif**

I could do a .gif but the issue with the GIF is that I don't have any control over the flow at which the snapshots are displayed.

**Tons of .ppt slides**

I could make one .ppt slide per .pdf slide but then, my computer doesn't seem powerful enough to offer nice transitions.

**Movie**

I could make a movie (although I don't know how to do that for the moment) out of my .pdf and I could probably (I don't really know how) include the movie in a .ppt slide and have control over the flow by pausing the video. The slight disadvantage to this method is that I can't easily go backward in time if needed during a presentation.

**HTML**

If it is possible to include HTML code in `.ppt`, I could eventually use the R-package `shiny` in order to pass the pdf images. That sounds like a weird solution though.

**What seems perfect to me**

I would love to just include the .pdf in a window within a single .ppt slide and be able to transit between the pages with a "next page" (`n` for example) and a "previous page" (`p` for example) keys.

---

*FYI*

- I am on MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.2
- Microsoft Office PowerPoint for Mac 2011, Version 14.4.8.

**EDIT**

Here is one page of the .pdf. Note: Slight improvement will still be made but text size should not change!

[image]

Comment: Please post one snapshot of your PDF. I want to know if the text in PDF is large enough to be read at full screen resolution. If yes, in PDF you can press CTRL+L  to make it full screen and navigate by using arrow keys - makes you feel like navigating thru a PPT

Comment: See edit. Thank you! Your solution sounds really cool. How should I import my pdf and can I just switch from regular mode to `CTRL+L` mode (where arrow keys will change the .pdf pages and not the .ppt slides).

Comment: Assuming you are using Adobe reader as your PDF viewer, you can use the CTRL+L keyboard shortcut to go to full screen mode. Then all the pages will exactly fit your screen. Once it fits your screen use PageUp or PageDown to navigate - I'm not a MAC user so it do not know how your system looks like

Comment: Oh I got it wrong at first place. I am aiming to have such functionality directly on my .ppt one of the reason is that I have to send my .ppt for my presentation and won't be able to switch from my .ppt presentation to the .pdf. I could make the whol presentation in .pdf but I have animations. So I suppose that the best solution would be to stick to .ppt. Does it make sense?

Comment: I'm running Office 2013 Power point - i tried to insert the PDF as object inside the PPT - and to my surprise, i'm not able to - I wonder why. Excel and Word allow embedding the PDF's as objects. What PPT software are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office PowerPoint for Mac 2011, Version 14.4.8. (Post edited) The only thing I tried was to seperate my .pdf into 1002 of .pdf and to insert them one to one as a picture (I did not do the whole 1002 pages)!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to load the powerpoint presentation, and the PDF at the same time?  Put the PDF in full-screen mode and just alt-tab (or the mac equivilent) to it at that point in the presentation

Comment: The issue is that I have to submit my `.ppt` online. I could probably make an exception and send the `.pdf` by email but I was hoping that another handy solution would exist.

Comment: @Remi.b - you can use the CTRL+L functionality mentioned above in its MAC parllel, but instead of opening the PDF manually, you could use a link to it from your .ppt. For online submission you can send both of them Zipped in a folder, that is to save a relative path to your pdf, or make it available online linking a URL from your .ppt

Comment: Ok, well it really sounds like there is no point at trying to directly include the `.pdf` in the presentation. I will indeed give up with this idea and just use the substitute you are suggesting.  If someone want to write an answer along the lines of "there is no point trying to do what you want, just switch between your `.pdf and `.ppt`", I will check it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to access the Internet while presenting? If so, you might want to take a look at flippingbook.com and see if their product might work for you. You would create a flipbook (electronic book, essentially) with a contents bar to allow easy navigation, then embed it in the PPT.